# Quiero publicar una transmisión usando RTMP en mi web pero no funciona

Tags: videojs

Si utilizo la URL en VLC puedo ver lo que estoy transmitiendo pero mi código en la web no funciona, que tengo mal? quiero mantenerlo opensourse porque $$, no importa si cambio videojs por otro.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.0.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Cargar Video.js -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.0.0/video.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Cargar complemento para RTMP -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/videojs-flash@2/dist/videojs-flash.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video
    id="my-player"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    poster="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png"
    data-setup='{}'
  >
    <!-- En este caso, el atributo "src" es la URL de la transmisión RTMP -->
    <source src="rtmp://3.144.159.61/live/micanal" type="rtmp/mp4"></source>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      Para ver este video por favor habilita JavaScript y considera actualizar a un navegador web que
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">soporte video HTML5</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script>
    // Inicializar Video.js con el complemento flash
    var player = videojs('my-player', {
      techOrder: ["flash", "html5"] // Priorizar Flash para reproducir RTMP
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mas información: la consola del navegador no me muestra errores, uso nginx para la retransmisión y funciona perfect. Si lo desean pueden ver en el VLC lo que estoy transmitiendo, gracias.

actualización: apagare el servidor nginx - UTC  03:42:01 Sábado,Julio 29, 2023

Answer (score 0):

En este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQAIwJyYmZ8), el señor explica otra manera de hacerlo usando hls, lo que implica configurar ssl y otras movidas. Personalmente, mi nginx lo tengo en un ec2, a pesar de eso es más o menos lo mismo, recomiendo que usen Amazon linux 2 porque batalle con la v2023, instalen todo con yum y presten extrema atención a las rutas, pues en el video el señor lo hace con Windows y cambia un poco, usen dos2unix para corregir los saltos de línea de los archivos después que suban sus archivos al servidor, no olviden abrir los puertos. La configuración que a mí me funciono en el archivo nginx.conf para que la visualización en la página fuera fluida es:

```
    rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    ping 30s;
    notify_method get;
    chunk_size 2048;

    application live {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_fragment 20;
        hls_path /usr/local/nginx/html/hls;
        record off;
    }
}
}

http {
proxy_cache_path /usr/local/nginx/html/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=10g inactive=60m;
    server {

    listen 8080; # Puerto para caché
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://restreaming.ddns.net:8080; # Dirección del servidor Nginx
        proxy_cache my_cache; # Nombre de la caché
        proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m; # Tiempo de validez de la caché
  }
}
```

Cabe resaltar que esta configuración es mía y no esta en el video.

Bueno, por ultimo agradezco que existe este espacio porque tal vez pueda servirle a otras personas, o no.